ArcGIS JS API Custom Parameters
I have many different types of layers (WMSLayer, FeatureLayer, CSVLayer, KMLLayer, etc.) in an ArcGIS JS v4.30 website. I need to be able to edit the data range of some of these layers.
My thought was to edit the customerParameters property of the layers that have such a property. I would set each layer to have the custom properties as such below.
customParameters: {
  STYLES: 'boxfill/turtlewatch2',
  COLORSCALERANGE: '17.5,18.5',
  FORMAT: 'image/png',
  NUMCOLORBANDS: 215
}

The goal would be to be able to set the range of a slider that has two sides. The slider could then be adjusted to set the range of the data. Once the data range is updated I could then use the layer's refresh method to update the presentation on the map.
Does this seem feasible (editing the COLORSCALERANGE option inside customerParameters) or is there a better way to go about what I am trying to accomplish?
I am aware that there are layers in the project that cannot be adjusted via the custom parameters.
